# Running 64 bit IE tab process on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, activex, 32-vs-64-bit

I have a 64 bit ActiveX component which I want to run inside IE.

I assumed when I run 64 bit IE, the tabs will also be 64 bit process and I will be able to create the ActiveX object.

But even in 64 bit IE, tabs are running as 32 bit process. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: Related SO question: [IE tabs are not running in 64 bit mode even after enabling Enhanced protected mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458588/ie-tabs-are-not-running-in-64-bit-mode-even-after-enabling-enhanced-protected-mo)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: That is specific windows 8 and above isnt't it? will it work for Win 7?

Comment: Surely this should work: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/32024-internet-explorer-11-enable-64-bit-tab-processes-epm.html

Comment: Do you have 32-bit add-ons? Use Tools->Manage add-ons.

Answer (score 4):

I have verified on Windows 7 64-bit with IE11 and UAC turned on,
and [the link](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/32024-internet-explorer-11-enable-64-bit-tab-processes-epm.html) given by @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 is correct:
Go in the IE menu Tools to Internet Options, Advanced tab, under Security,
and check "Enable Enhanced Protected Mode". On newer version of Windows one also
needs to check "Enable 64-bit processes for Enhanced Protected Mode". Re-launching IE was enough in my case,
although the documentation advises to restart the computer.

I had no add-ons installed at all. The documentation says that 32-bit
add-ons are disabled in 64-bit mode. Another note is that this also worked
in Windows 10 with UAC disabled, so UAC does not seem important here.

This should do the job, but if for some reason it does not, there is another
solution, which is in the Registry to create under the key
`CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` a DWORD (32-bit)
entry named `TabProcGrowth` with zero as its value.
When this registry entry is set to 0, the tabs run in the same process as the manager process, which is always 64-bit on a 64-bit operating system.
Documentation may be [found here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2716529) (for IE10, but was
verified by me for IE11). Restarting IE seems enough for this registry setting
to be enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution for Win7. I need to create a regular user (i.e. not administrator) with UAC enabled. Then Enable Enhanced Protected Mode and also make sure that the zone from where the webpage is loading has protected mode enabled. Then I am able to launch 64 bit tab process without setting TabProcGrowth.